# How does one use multiple modules in fortran without name clashes

Tags: fortran

Suppose in my main program I want to use two modules, module a and module b. These two modules independently use a third module, module c. Am I correct in thinking that name clashes will result? i.e the declared entities in module c will effectively be redeclared in both modules a and b as a result of the USE statements. If so, how does one get around this? Is it possible to have a PRIVATE statement somewhere to avoid the trouble?

Thanks for taking the time to read the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Name clashes won't result.

Yes, public entities in `c` will be use-associated in `a` and `b`, and then in your main program, but no ambiguity will be introduced.

```
module c
  integer int
end module c

module a
  use c
end module a

module b
  use c
end module b

program main
  use a
  use b
  ! use c

  int = 1
end program
```

Your confusion may be "declared entities in module c will effectively be redeclared": there is association, but the same declaration is used.  This is in contrast with, say, C header files.

Comment: Just for completeness sake, if you indeed run into a situation, where a name-clash would arise, you can make use of the only clause, to rename entities in the use statement.

Comment: And to expand on that comment, such an ambiguity can come about by, say, an `only` clause on `c` in `b` and also there re-using a name from `c` not use-associated.