# The same named entity in PETSc and MPI - conflict

Tags: fortran, petsc

I have an existing Fortran code using MPI for parallel work.
I am interested in adding some of the PETSc solvers (KSP specifically), however when including the relevant .h or .h90 files (petsc, petscsys, petscksp, etc...) I get a problem with variables that share the same name as the MPI ones.

i.e.:

```
  error #6405: The same named entity from different modules and/or program units cannot be referenced.   [MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION]
  error #6405: The same named entity from different modules and/or program units cannot be referenced.   [MPI_SUM]
  error #6405: The same named entity from different modules and/or program units cannot be referenced.   [MPI_COMM_WORLD]
and so on.
```

(using ics/composer_xe_2011_sp1.6.233 and ics/impi/4.0.3.008 and petsc 3.6.0, also tried older petsc version 3.5.4)

All of these are defined equally in both MPI and PETSc - is there a way to resolve this conflict and use both?

I'll point out that I DO NOT WANT to replace MPI calls with PETSc calls, as the code should have an option to run independent of PETSc.

As for minimal code, cleaning up the huge code is an issue apparently, so I've made the following simple example which includes the relevant parts:

```
program mpitest


implicit none
use mpi

! Try any of the following:
!!!#include "petsc.h"
!!!#include "petsc.h90"
!!!#include "petscsys.h"
! etc'


integer :: ierr, error
integer :: ni=256, nj=192, nk=256
integer :: i,j,k

real, allocatable :: phi(:,:,:)


integer :: mp_rank, mp_size
real :: sum_phi,max_div,max_div_final,sum_div_final,sum_div


  call mpi_init(ierr)
  call mpi_comm_rank(mpi_comm_world,mp_rank,ierr)
  call mpi_comm_size(mpi_comm_world,mp_size,ierr)




allocate(phi(nj,nk,0:ni/mp_size+1))

        sum_phi = 0.0
        do i=1,ni/mp_size
           do k=1,nk
              do j=1,nj
                 sum_phi = sum_phi + phi(j,k,i)
              enddo
           enddo
        enddo


sum_phi = sum_phi / real(ni/mp_size*nk*nj)
        call mpi_allreduce(sum_div,sum_div_final,1,mpi_double_precision,mpi_sum, &
             mpi_comm_world,ierr)
        call mpi_allreduce(max_div,max_div_final,1,mpi_double_precision,mpi_max, &
             mpi_comm_world,ierr)


call mpi_finalize(error)

deallocate(phi)


WRITE(*,*) 'Done'

end program mpitest
```

This happens directly when PETSc headers are included and vanishes when the include is removed.

Comment: You probably don't need both fortran and fortran90 tags -- just fortran should be enough (you don't show *any* code, if you really do have a requirement for fortran90 specifc solutions then you probably need to show some code/explain why). Note that [petscsys.h](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-dev/include/petscsys.h.html) has an `include <mpi.h>` line (L130) which you presumably also have? If not then I guess you've got the `include petscsys` line at module level somewhere and have a `use MODULENAME` statement somewhere without the `only` qualifier that means you bring in these defs again.

Comment: You should really try to show a [mcve] so that we can work out what exactly is going on. The suggestions in my previous comment are only a couple of the possible ways this could arise so showing your code is vital.

Comment: There are different aspects to consider, but we do need a more complete example to say much more.  You could consider renaming, or how [modules can handle things](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22209818).

Comment: Both renaming and only is likely to help but you should show the code. Take it as a lecture, you would have probably received a good answer within minutes or an hour if you showed the important details...

Comment: @VladimirF, I'm sorry for not including the example earlier, however it was due to extreme lack of time, not lack of knowledge that it is required.

Comment: There was an answer which is now applicable and I hope the author will undelete it. It pointed to this resource http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/Sys/UsingFortran.html , but it said more. In general you should now that using `include "mpif.h"` instead of proper Fortran modules is obsolete and not recommended. Even the more better `use mpi` has now an even more modern alternative in MPI 3.

Comment: I'll point out that initially I worked with "use mpi" and "use petscXXX" rather than using "include" - but it had absolutely no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so the answer has been found:

PETSc does not favor Fortran much and, therefore, does not function the same way as it does with C/C++ and uses different definitions.
For C/C++ one would use the headers in `/include/petscXXX.h` and everything will be fine, moreover the hierarchical structure already includes dependent .h files (i.e. including petscksp.h will include petscsys.h, petscvec.h and so on).

NOT IN FORTRAN.

First and foremost,for FORTRAN one needs to include headers in `/include/petsc/finclude/petscXXXdef.h` (or .h90 if PETSc is compiles with that flag). Note that the files are located in a different include folder and are petscxxx**def**.h.

Then 'use petscXXX' will work along with MPI without conflicting.